# How can I modify java source code using Python3 and ANTLR4?

Tags: python, antlr4

I have a set of Java source codes and I need to modify these .java files (remove whitespaces, comments, etc.) For that purpose, I downloaded the Java lexer and parser files from [this](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java) repository and compiled it using antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar. I also installed the antlr4-python3-runtime using pip.

I tried removing the multiline comment in the sample HelloWorld program with the code below but i got the following traceback. How can I resolve this problem?

For compiling the lexer and parser:

```
java -jar [path_to_antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar] -Dlanguage=Python3 [path_to_lexer_file]
java -jar [path_to_antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar] -Dlanguage=Python3 [path_to_parser_file]
```

Sample java file:

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        /*
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        */
    }

}
```

Python code for altering files:

```
source = open("./HelloWorld.java", "r")
codeStream = InputStream(source.read())
lexer = JavaLexer.JavaLexer(codeStream)
token_stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
token_stream.fill()
rewriter = TokenStreamRewriter.TokenStreamRewriter(token_stream)
for token in token_stream.tokens:
    if token.type == JavaLexer.JavaLexer.COMMENT:
        rewriter.deleteToken(token)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alp/PycharmProjects/JavaParsingTutorial/parser.py", line 31, in <module>
    rewriter.deleteToken(token)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/antlr4/TokenStreamRewriter.py", line 80, in deleteToken
    self.delete(self.DEFAULT_PROGRAM_NAME, token, token)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/antlr4/TokenStreamRewriter.py", line 88, in delete
    self.replace(program_name, from_idx, to_idx, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/antlr4/TokenStreamRewriter.py", line 71, in replace
    if any((from_idx > to_idx, from_idx < 0, to_idx < 0, to_idx >= len(self.tokens.tokens))):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'CommonToken' and 'CommonToken'
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)